# Python 2.7.6 Installation Error on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, installation, python

I'm trying to install Python 2.7.6 on a HP-Mini 210 Netbook just to run some simple tasks.

I get the following error when the installer is doing "Status: Publishing Product Information"
[image: http://i.imgur.com/1a1DAAi.png]
I am trying to install Python but I'm running into following error:

The operating system is Windows 7 Start, Service Pack 1. 32bit (x86)

I've looked for quite a while trying to find a fix for this problem but can't find anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, make sure you're not trying to install the 64-bit version of Python.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nope it's a 32bit installer on a 32bit operating system :(

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact that you're using the bare-bones **Windows Starter 7** edition of Windows 7 and something needed to complete the installation has been left out (which technically may be a bug in the Python installer if it's supposed to support that edition of the OS).

Comment: Hey martineau, What would you suggest? It's using the default windows operating system that was on the netbook as there isn't a DVD Drive :S

Comment: There should be an Anytime Upgrade option built-in. You don't need the original install CD/DVD to use it and you could upgrade to Home Basic or Home Premium. Upgrading isn't free however...nevertheless I think it would be your best option unless someone here knows of a workaround for this issue.

Comment: To clarify, you don't even need a DVD drive to utilize Anytime Upgrade.

Comment: I suggest you re-post your question on stackoverflow.com where you might get better responses.